# How to add a new line before a specific string

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have  a file like this (it shows in single line)

```
Status: 012, Id: -1434606409zzzzz, Number: +9257884Status: 013, Id: -1434606409efwe, Number: +92465745Status: 014, Id: -1434606409fwe6, Number: +9212345
```

I want to show format like this

```
Status: 012, Id: -1434606409zzzzz, Number: +9257884
Status: 013, Id: -1434606409efwe, Number: +92465745
Status: 014, Id: -1434606409fwe6, Number: +9212345
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/Status/\n&/g' file
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you and this community :) Its the best where I get QUICKEST replies :) thank youuuuuuu all